# Show only nth tick LINE on x-axis for Chart.js diagram

Tags: chart.js

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while but am getting no nearer to a solution due to the mass of deleted documentation and hacky answers for previous versions of the library.

I'm working on a chart with ChartJS v2 with quarterly-month names along the x-axis, and I've set my labels so that only every 4th label is shown (i.e. one per year). The result is this:

[image]

However, I would like to have it such that the tick *lines* also only appear on every 4th x-axis entry at the same point as the labels. Is this possible?

My current script tag is as follows:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = 600;
    ctx.canvas.height = 420;
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {

          < snipped for brevity >

        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
              mode: 'index',
              intersect: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        userCallback: function(item, index) {
                            if (index%4) return "";
                            return item;
                        },
                        autoSkip: false
                    },
                    display: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Is this possible to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace your tick­*'s* `userCallback` function with the following ...

```
userCallback: function(item, index) {
   if (!(index % 4)) return item;
}
```

Basically, you don't need to *return* any empty string for the label that you wish to hide. If you do not *return* anything *(for the label you don't want)*, it won't draw any tick *(as well as gridline)* for that label.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Standard Rating',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(209, 230, 245, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(56, 163, 236, 1)',
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'label',
         intersect: false
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               userCallback: function(item, index) {
                  if (!(index % 4)) return item;
               },
               autoSkip: false
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but is there a way so that the text for the axis is not inclined but straight ?

Comment: The tooltip shows undefined for x value, is there a fix for this ?